# Unable to get OpportunityLineItem using uiRelatedListApi

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to display related list of OpportunityLineItem in a LWC which is used in recordDetail page in Community for Opportunity. However I encounter this error (note I log in as System Administrator user, so I can access to all records):

> {"status":400,"body":{"message":"The related lists UI API currently does not support this related list","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"},"headers":{},"ok":false,"statusText":"Bad Request","errorType":"fetchResponse"}

```
@wire(getRelatedListRecords, {
    parentRecordId: '0068b00001Q1bo4AAB',
    relatedListId: 'OpportunityLineItems',
    fields: ['OpportunityLineItem.Id','OpportunityLineItem.UnitPrice','OpportunityLineItem.ProductCode'],
    sortBy: ['OpportunityItemLine.ProductCode']
})lineItemsInfo({error, data}) {
    if(data){            
        this.records = data.records;
    } else if(error){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
};
```

Any suggestion, please! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce doesn't support all the standard objects for `ui*api`, and `OpportunityLineItem` is one of them. I faced smiler issue with this object with `uiRecordApi`.

For your current requirement, you need to call separate Apex call via Imperative or Wire to fetch the records of this object.

Reference
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_supported_objects